failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount41583267/#: no such file or directory
I am new to Docker and I'm trying to build a ASP.NET Core & React app, but having problems with Docker Compose. I get the error "failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount41583267/#: no such file or directory", when the backend Dockerfile is running.
Here is that file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"]


And here is my docker-compose.yml for the backend:
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./TestApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
      MONGODB_URI: ${MONGODB_URI}
    ports:
      - "5000:80" 


Above is the folder structure.
I have tried restarting Docker Desktop, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, checked .dockerignore file for faulty ignores, but I just can't get it to work.

It's unclear from your question but -- I assume -- the docker-compose.yml that you included is (the docker-compose.yml file shown) in the docker-compose folder. This folder is a peer to TestApp and you will complicate life (and cause problems) in defining the context. You would be better placed to hang everything off a single (context) folder (perhaps TestApp?) and, for simplicity, you should just keep Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in this root folder too. If you do this, your docker-compose.yml's context would be . (==TestApp).

Is that exactly the Dockerfile that caused the error, or does the Dockerfile have comments?

@BMitch The Dockerfile had comments, but removing them didn't fix the issue.

The provided error message pointed to a comment that is not actually a comment. It's a sign that the error was not generated by the file you provided us.

@BMitch You are correct. I solved the problem and posted my solution here.

Solved.
I had named the service "backend" in docker-compose.yml and still had the old name (in my case "testapp") in docker-compose.override.yml. Matching the service names in these two files solved the problem for me.
